# Why won't my function activate when I call it?

Tags: python, function

```
import random
def main():
   num_guesses = 4


   instruction_file=open('instructions.txt', 'r')

   list_of_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'mango']
   answer=random.choice(list_of_words)
   puzzle=['_'] * len(answer)




   def display_instructions(instruction_file):
      file_contents=instruction_file.read()
      instruction_file=instruction_file.close()
      print(file_contents)





   def get_guess(num_guesses):
      print('The number of guesses remaining is ' + str(num_guesses)+ '.') 
      letter_input = input("Guess a letter ")
      return letter_input

   def update_puzzle_string(letter_input,puzzle,answer):
      if get_guess(num_guesses) in answer:
         for i,x in enumerate(answer):
            if x is get_guess:
               puzzle[i]=letter_input
               return True


   def display_puzzle_string(puzzle):
      print('The current state of the puzzle is '+str(puzzle))

   def is_word_found(puzzle,answer):
      is_word_found=True
      puzzle_string=print(''.join(puzzle))
      if puzzle_string == answer:
         return False





   def play_game(answer,puzzle):
      while True:
         display_puzzle_string(puzzle)
         get_guess(num_guesses)
         update_puzzle_string(get_guess,puzzle,answer)
         print(str(puzzle))



   is_word_found(puzzle,answer)
   display_instructions(instruction_file)         
   play_game(answer,puzzle)







main()
```

Sorry for formatting issues. The goal of this program is to collect a guess from a user then compare it to a randomly selected word from a list after doing so it updates a puzzle that has blanks where the letter belongs, if all letters of the word are guessed, user is told they are correct. User gets 4 guesses. It is basically hangman. When I execute this program it just prints the instructions, the initial puzzle state, requests a guess then keeps asking for guesses. I don't understand why this isn't working. I'll implement the number of guesses after I get help with this.

Comment: Your code has serious indentation problems, which with Python makes it really difficult to understand. Can you correct that? Just edit your question, paste your code, select it, and use the `{}` button format it as code. Don't use the backticks for big code blocks.

Comment: @FredLarson Done, thank you!

Comment: When I run this code (after adding `import random` at the top), it keeps asking for input.

Comment: @JohnGordon that is my problem, I can't get it to stop asking for guesses.

Comment: Oh.  I thought you said the problem was that it asks for a guess and then stops.  Did you edit the question?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, very sorry, I didn't sleep well last night.

Comment: You should take a more "step by step" approach when programming, it seems that a lots of things in your code have for base functions that aren't doing what you expect them to do. Also its you confuse some of your functions with variables, and that you don't use what your functions are returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
def main():
    num_guesses = 4
    instruction_file=open('instructions.txt', 'r')

    list_of_words = ['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'mango']
    answer=random.choice(list_of_words)
    puzzle=['_'] * len(answer)

    def display_instructions(instruction_file):
        file_contents=instruction_file.read()
        instruction_file=instruction_file.close()
        print(file_contents)

    def get_guess(num_guesses):
        print('The number of guesses remaining is ' + str(num_guesses)+ '.') 
        letter_input = input("Guess a letter: ")
        return letter_input

    def update_puzzle_string(letter_input,puzzle,answer):
        for i,x in enumerate(answer):
            if x is letter_input:
                puzzle[i]=letter_input
        return

    def display_puzzle_string(puzzle):
        print('The current state of the puzzle is '+str(puzzle))

    def is_word_found(puzzle,answer):
        is_word_found=True
        puzzle_string=print(''.join(puzzle))
        if puzzle_string == answer:
            return False
                
    def play_game(answer,puzzle):
        while True:
            display_puzzle_string(puzzle) #display '_ _ _ _ _'
            guess = get_guess(num_guesses)
            update_puzzle_string(guess,puzzle,answer)
            #print(str(puzzle)) #this statement is causing the repetitive puzzle prints

    is_word_found(puzzle,answer)
    display_instructions(instruction_file)
    play_game(answer,puzzle)

main()
```

After fixing your formatting issues, the code now repeatedly asks for a guess and takes input. I think the issue mostly existed in formatting because I get no errors now. Also, did you have random imported before? Cheers

## EDIT:

See changes to both `update_puzzle_string()` and `play_game`. You repeatedly called the get_guess function rather than using its initial return value.
[image: example (note that repeat letters are not supported under this code)]

## EDIT 2: (refer to comments of this answer)

See `update_puzzle_string()` for the change regarding "multiple of the same letter in the answer"
[image: program now places all of the right letter in place]

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I meant that it keeps asking for a guess rather than updating the puzzle string with the guess. Like it just keeps asking over and over for a guess rather than proceeding to update puzzle or print the updated puzzle.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so lost it was unbelievable, you're a life saver.

Comment: @Mathissohardlmao no problem, glad I could help! Thanks for accepting the answer :)

Comment: Unrelated to original question, but why does the guess not fill in all appropriate letters of the word. For ex. the guess e for watermelon only fills in one of the e's.

Comment: @Mathissohardlmao see my updated answer on that for the code change.

Answer (score 0):

So your error was not being able to stop the software?

You can use is_word_found inside play_game and then break if found.

Like this:

```
def play_game(answer,puzzle):
    while True:
        display_puzzle_string(puzzle)
        get_guess(num_guesses)
        update_puzzle_string(get_guess,puzzle,answer)
        if is_word_found(puzzle, answer):
            print("You won!")
            break
        print(str(puzzle))
```

Break will stop `while True` infinite loop

Comment: His initial issue was a loop created by calling functions repeatedly instead of saving the result of the function into a variable and using that.